# Android overlapping layouts

Tags: android, layout, inflate

I has a Sliding ViewPager with about 5 pages. Each layout is inflated like this:

```
  public static class SectionFragment extends Fragment {
  ...
  @Override
  public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ...) {
      ...
      rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.gridpage1,container,false);
      ...
  }
```

Now I want to check if a condition is true and if Yes, I want to inflate the gridpage1 layout first, then another layout on top of it.

How can i do this? All I need is the help on inflating two views one on top of the other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inflating a view basically just means creating it from an XML file and returning it.

In your specific case, you just need to return your fragment content view from the `onCreateView` function. This must be a single view, so if your condition is true and you want 2 views do the following:

1. Create a `FrameLayout` view yourself programmatically

   Something like: `FrameLayout frameLayout = new FrameLayout(context);`
2. Add the 1st view to your `FrameLayout` after inflating it

   Either do `frameLayout.addView(inflater.inflate(R.layout.gridpage1,frameLayout,false));`
    or even `inflater.inflate(R.layout.gridpage1,frameLayout,true);` is enough because `true` tells it to add the view to the container.
3. Add the 2nd view to your `FrameLayout` after inflating it
4. Return the `FrameLayout` from your `onCreateView`

**Addition:**

How to save the reference to each view:

Option 1:

```
View v1 = inflater.inflate(R.layout.gridpage1,frameLayout,false);
this.v1Reference = v1;
frameLayout.addView(v1);
```

Option 2:

```
inflater.inflate(R.layout.gridpage1,frameLayout,true);
this.v1Reference = frameLayout.findViewById(...);
```

Comment: With this option, can I hide the views? I only want 1 showing at any given time. Like to toggle switch...

Comment: Sure, you can keep a reference to each one or find it using its id and then call view.setVisibility(..)

Comment: OKay, Ill give it ago and will post if I need help. Thank you

Comment: Another option instead of hiding and showing each view inside the frameLayout is calling removeView(v1) and addView(v2) accordingly.. as long as you keep a reference to v1 and v2 they will not be freed

Comment: Okay, one question, how do I get the reference to the Views when im adding to the frameLayout

Comment: If you're inflating with false, then you're adding them manually, so just save the reference as a class variable in your fragment. If you're inflating with true, then you'll have to call frameLayout.findViewById(..) and give each a different id in your xml

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `<include />` tag in your main layout and then hide/show the views you want with `setVisibility(View.GONE/VISIBLE)`.
For example:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello_world" />

    <include android:id="@+id/gridpage1_layout" layout="@layout/gridpage1"/>
    <include android:id="@+id/gridpage2_layout" layout="@layout/gridpage2"/>
...

</RelativeLayout>
```

And in your Fragment, you can inflate only the root layout and find the other views by ID.

Comment: `ViewStub` is probably better for this case.